# How to check if the sheet has been removed?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I use the following function to read the spreadsheet by ID:

```
  readSpreadsheet = (spreadsheetId) => {
    return window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      range: this.props.sheetName + '!A:A',
    });
  };
```

However when the sheet was moved to trash, it can still be retrieved like normal. I don't want to write data into the removed sheet, so how can I know if the sheet has been removed or not?

Comment: Try removing the sheet using the [DeleteSheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletesheetrequest) request in Sheets API v4. I tried deleting a sheet and getting the value within that sheet and an `error 400` returned as expected.

Comment: Sounds like a good trick! I will give it a try. Thanks Mr.Rebot!

Comment: If it helps, I will post this as answer

Comment: No, Mr. Rebot. It's not working. Most likely you did not send the correct request. As I tested, no matter the spreadsheet is removed or not, we can call deleteSheet to delete a sheet from the spreadsheet. You are not allowed to remove the last sheet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the Google Sheets V4 documentation. Looks like they do not have this function available. Since the sheet is saved in Google Drive, I am able to use Google Drive API to check if file has been removed or not.
Some example code as below:

```
window.gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2').then(() => {
  window.gapi.client.drive.files.get(
    { fileId: spreadsheetId }
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response && response.result && !response.result.explicitlyTrashed) {
      this.setState({ spreadsheetId });
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```